# Why won't Borgakh The Steel Heart fight?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I was walking through Mzinchaleft with Borgakh who is at the moment my very favorite follower, and when she got attacked by a Dwarven Sphere, she didn't fight back. After a minute or so, I got annoyed and killed the thing. Why didn't Borgakh fight back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a common bug that can be solved by telling your follower to leave and then telling him to join again.